# rsync macos Operation not permitted and skipping file deletion

Tags: macos, terminal, rsync

If I type the following command in the terminal,

```
sudo rsync -a -u -v -progress --delete --stats -n Externe1/ Externe3/
```

I got the following error:

> building file list ... rsync: opendir "/Volumes/Externe1/.Spotlight-V100" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding `--exclude '.Spotlight-V100'` and also removing `--delete-excluded`.

I'd also recommend ignoring both `.DS_Store` and `.fseventsd` in macOS. This is my current default command:

```
rsync -ru --progress --copy-links --delete \
  --exclude '.DS_Store' --exclude '.Spotlight-V100' --exclude '.fseventsd' \
  [SRC] [DEST]
```

Comment: For future users who might read this helpful answer: please note that the exclude path is always relative to the source, eg. if you use `--exclude "/directory/file.txt"`, rsync will look for `"[SRC]/directory/file.txt"` ([source](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/))